# Delete downloaded files in Firefox and Safari

Tags: macos, safari, firefox

I have a Mac Pro with Firefox and Safari as browsers.
I have tried several methods to delete individual downloaded files while in both browsers. How can I delete downloaded files?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you are saving the downloaded files. By default, they are saved in ~/Downloads (the Downloads folder in your home folder). This folder is a stack on your Dock (unless you've removed it) and files can be deleted from there.